# Passing a PHP Array into jplayer playlist

Tags: javascript, dynamic, jplayer, playlist

I am a beginner programmer and I'm trying to create a dynamically populated playlist from files in a folder.  I have found a result here [Dynamically populate playlist with JSON from PHP in jPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393273/dynamically-populate-playlist-with-json-from-php-in-jplayer?rq=1).  This would allow me to do what I need.

However, I want to understand why my method does not work.  I"m able to get an array into javascript using the myPlaylist variable that looks like the following from console.log.

```
Array [
    ""title":"Song1","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song1.mp3"",
    ""title":"Song2","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song2.mp3"",
    ""title":"Song3","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song3.mp3"",
    ""title":"Song4","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song4.mp3"", 
    ""title":"Song5","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song5.mp3""
  ]
```

When I run this and jplayer playlist comes up in the browser it lists 5 items, but lists them all as undefined.  Again, I"m sure I'm doing something stupid, but I can't figure out why they are all undefined.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to treat your playlist elements as objects, you need to wrap them with brackets instead of quotes. The final array output should look like this:

```
[
    {"title":"Song1","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song1.mp3"},
    {"title":"Song2","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song2.mp3"},
    {"title":"Song3","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song3.mp3"},
    {"title":"Song4","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song4.mp3"},
    {"title":"Song5","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song5.mp3"}
]
```

Also, I'm not sure how you're preparing the file paths, but you should know that `\` is an escape character in JavaScript. You have to either "escape the escape character" by using `\\` instead, or else [use the escape() and unescape() functions](http://forums.asp.net/t/1690320.aspx?how+to+pass+file+path+as+a+query+string+from+javascript) to convert the file paths.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  However, it still doesn't work.  It still shows as undefined. I have my array formatted as follows.

    Array [ "{"title":"Song1","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song1.mp3"}", "{"title":"Song2","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song2.mp3"}", "{"title":"Song3","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song3.mp3"}", "{"title":"Song4","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song4.mp3"}", "{"title":"Song5","artist":"Choir","mp3":"C:\xampp\htdocs\media\Song5.mp3"}" ]

The leading and trailing " are only from console.log. Not there on alert

Comment: I'd need to see the code that's generating the array to know more. Can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: The link is below.  The array is generated using PHP.  Then the array is passed into javascript using json_encode().

http://jsfiddle.net/EngiNeer732/2heh1cb8/

Comment: Okay. I don't have Windows so I can't test this further, but the problem appears to be with how you're constructing the file path, and also that you need to use `JSON.parse()`. See http://jsfiddle.net/2heh1cb8/3/

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've been working on this but still can't seem to get it to work.  I can't get the filename or the mp3 file path to populate. I assume I just need to re-write the php function that generates the array in javascript. Also, I thought jplayer playlist accepts JSON formatted arrays as shown in this post.

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393273/dynamically-populate-playlist-with-json-from-php-in-jplayer

Thanks again for your help! I may just have to punt and write it in javascript. Just stubborn and can't understand why this doesn't work when the log format looks good.